# ReloadData doesn't fire cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, tableview, reloaddata

I know this has been asked over and over again. I've tried all given solution but still it didn't work.  I have set the datasource and delegate to my table view and also set it to my pointers.

Here is my code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section     {
NSLog(@"%i", resultSoap.count);
return resultSoap.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell.

NSString *cellValue = [resultSoap objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
NSLog(@"Celldisplay");

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

return cell;
}
```

I've called the `reloadData` on my `viewDidLoad:` method. The thing is, it fired `numberOfRowsInSection:` method and I get the row count correct but it didn't fire this `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Any solution?

Comment: How many row is it returning? In debug mode, can you see the content of resultSoap?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
urtableview.delegate = self;
urtableview.datasource = self;
```

After declaring the resultsoap array in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It must be due to calling reload method of table when table view datasource array *"resultsoap"* is empty.
    Make sure that your datasource array is not empty and check if the array has objects saved.

Because if `numberOfRowsInSection` returns 0 then the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` may not be called.
    And this must be in your case.

Answer (score -3):

Please Add Bellow Code In Your Suitable Methods.

if You had take Simple Controller and Add Table View than

In your Header File .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface TaskAndTax : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    IBOutlet UITableView *MyTableView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *MyTableView;
@end
```

And in Your .m File

```
@synthesize MyTableView;

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [MyTableView reloadData];
}
```

And Kindly Connect IBOutlet Of TableView in Our Case its MyTableView to TableView in XIB file.
[image: In My case Its getclientTable.]